# UTF-8 characters are not displayed at all

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, java-native-interface

I have the following flow: In Java I'm reading some strings from a file (the file is encoded with UTF-8 - i checked it with Notepad++) and via JNI sending them to C. From there a webapp picks the strings up and displays them in an iframe. The problem is that none of the special characters are being displayed (at all - not even some wierd characters or such). It's just like you do a replace all UTF-8 chars with empty string. Do you happen to have any ideas?

UPDATE 1
I don't have control only on the java part, the rest of the components are out of my reach. I can see that the iframe has set the charset to iso-8859-1 (latin1), but even so I believe that SOME wierd characters should appear. I also changed the encoding of the file to ISO-8859-1 and using in java getBytes("ISO-8859-1"). I even start the Tomcat container with the VM option of file.encoding=ISO-8859-1. The webapp that picks the string up is on a different machine and container than my java code.

Comment: Have you told the browser that you are sending it UTF-8 via the content type or a meta tag?

Comment: Yes I checked - updated question

Comment: Are you saying that regular characters are displayed, just not special characters?

Comment: @zenzelezz , yes that is correct